# Rails 4 Adding Multiple Audio Files to an audio_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, audio

So for part of a project I'm working on I am trying to build a playlist of tracks.  I'm using [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com) to create an audio player and [mep-feature-playlist](https://github.com/duozersk/mep-feature-playlist) to create a playlist.  I'm able to load all audio files that I want to into my Rails app however they are all rendered with the actual file name `Track 1.m4a` instead of the name of the track itself `Track 1`.  I know that if I were working with just one audio file I could use the title: attribute to set the title of the track.  My question though is, how do I add multiple titles to multiple tracks within a single audio_tag?  If I create separate audio_tags MediaElement.js and mep-feature-playlist will create separate audio players.  Here's the way my code looks now:

playlist/show.html.erb:

```
<h1>Playlist Example</h1>

<%= audio_tag("Track 1.m4a", "Track 2.m4a", "Track 3.m4a", "Track 4.m4a", "Track 5.m4a", "Track 6.m4a", "Track 7.m4a") %>

<script>
    $(function(){
      $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
          loop: true,
          shuffle: true,
          playlist: true,
          audioHeight: 30,
          playlistposition: 'bottom',
          features: ['playlistfeature', 'prevtrack', 'playpause', 'nexttrack', 'loop', 'shuffle', 'playlist', 'current', 'progress', 'duration', 'volume']
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting title when giving multiple audio sources does not seem to supported in `audio_tag` helper. However you write your own helper.

Given sources

```
sources = [{src: path_to_audio('1.mp3'), title: 'soo'}, {src: path_to_audio('2.mp3'), title: 'haa'}]
```

You could write the following helper:

```
# Methods added to this helper will be available to all templates in the application.
module ApplicationHelper
  def audio_tag_multiple(sources)
    content_tag(:audio) do
      sources.map do |source|
        safe_concat(tag :source,source, true)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This would generate markup similar to one given below:

```
<audio>
  <source src="1.mp3" title="soo">
  <source src="2.mp3" title="haa">
</audio>
```

Hope it helps